# How to find the position of all array items from a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm brand new to programming so I apologize if this is a simple question.

I had a unique practice problem that I'm not quite sure how to solve:

I'm dealing with two arrays, both arrays are pulled from HTML elements on the page, one array is representing a bunch of states, and the next array is representing their populations. The point of the problem is to print the name of the states and their less than average populations.

To find and print all of the populations that are less than the average I used this code:

```
  function code6() {
    // clears screen.
    clr();
    // both variables pull data from HTML elements with functions.
    var pop = getData2();
    var states = getData();
    var sum = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < pop.length; i++ ){
      sum += parseInt( pop[i], 10 );
      var avg = sum/pop.length;
      if (pop[i] < avg) {
        println(pop[i]);

        // other functions used in the code to get data, print, and clear the screen.
        function getData() {
          var dataSource = getElement("states");
          var numberArray = dataSource.value.split('\n');
          // Nothing to split returns ['']
          if (numberArray[0].length > 0) {
            return(numberArray);
          } else {
            return [];
          }  
      }

    // Get the data from second data column
    function getData2() {
      var dataSource = getElement("pops");
      var numberArray = dataSource.value.split('\n');
      // Nothing to split returns ['']
      if (numberArray[0].length > 0) {
        return(numberArray);
      } else {
        return [];
      }  
    }

    // Clear the 'output' text area
    function clr() {
      var out = getElement("output");
      out.value = "";
    }

    // Print to the 'output' HTML element and ADDS the line break
    function println(x) {
      if (arguments.length === 0) x = '';
      print(x + '\n');
    }
```

Now I just need to know how to get the value of these positions within the array so I can pull out the same positions from my states array and display them both side by side. Both arrays have the identical amount of items.

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance to anyone who has time to take a look at this.

Best regards,

-E

Comment: stackoverflow search is your friend

Comment: `clr()` and `println()` are not JavaScript. Are you sure you are not asking about Java, which is entirely different than JavaScript? If not, where is the rest of the code that relates to these functions?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use eslint. Your code is not very idiomatic, and has allot of glaring issues. Eslint will help you improve.

Comment: Please share sample data returned by your two getData() functions

Comment: Thanks for all of the replays so far, I just edited the posting with the other functions included.

Comment: I have edited your code to include indentation. It appears that you have left off the closing curly brace for the `code6` function.

Answer (score 1):

Its a little hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish, but I guess you are going for something like:

```js
'use strict'

function code6() {
  const populations = ['39000000', '28000000', '21000000'];
  const stateNames = ['california', 'texas', 'florida'];
  const states = populations.map((population, i) => ({
    'name': stateNames[i],
    'population': Number(population),
  }));

  const sum = states.reduce((sum, state) => sum + state.population, 0);
  const average = sum / populations.length;
  states
      .filter(state => state.population < average)
      .forEach(state => {
        const name = state.name;
        const population = state.population;
        console.log(`state name: ${name}, population: ${population}`);
      });
}

// run the code
code6();
// state name: texas, population: 28000000
// state name: florida, population: 21000000
```

I took the liberty of refactoring your code to be a little more modern (es6) and Idiomatic. I hope its not to confusing for you. Feel free to ask any questions about it.

In short you should use:

- 'use strict' at the top of your files
- const/let
- use map/filter/forEach/reduce to iterate lists.
- use meaningfull names

, and you should avoid:

- classic indexed for-loop
- parseInt

, and pretty much never ever use:

- var

Comment: Nice solution, but two things.  First, I think you need `.filter(state => state.population < avg)` (not **>**).  Second is there any reason not to replace the final clause with `.forEach(state => console.log(`state name: ${state.name}, population: ${state.population}))`?  I don't see the temporary variables adding anything useful.

Comment: You are right, it should be less then avg, my bad; I will fix.

Comment: As for your point about `${state.name}`, it would make the composite string line not fit within 80 char, which means its way to long, IMO. I also thing it would b less readable. Its mostly a style ting I would say. I prefer to have more lines rather then long lines.

Comment: I briefly considered using deconstruction, i.e. `({name, population}) = > {}` but that doesn't work with my node install for some reason, and i figured it was going to far in using advanced features considering this is a response to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If your `states` array is built with corresponding indices to your `pop` one, like this:

```
states; //=> ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', ...]
pop; //=> [4863300, 741894, 6931071, ...]
```

then you could simply update your print statement to take that into account:

```
  if (pop[i] < avg) {
    println(state[i] + ': ' + pop[i]);
  }
```

Or some such.

However, working with shared indices can be a very fragile way to use data.  Could you rethink your `getData` and `getData2` functions and combine them into one that returns a structure more like this the following?

```
states; //=> [
        //     {name: 'Alabama', pop: 4863300}
        //     {name: 'Alaska', pop: 741894},
        //     {name: 'Arizona', pop: 6931071},
        //    ...]
```

This would entail changes to the code above to work with the `pop` property of these objects, but it's probably more robust.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for the help. I'll work on getting better and change my code to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If your `pop` and `state` looks like:

```
var state = ['state1', 'state2', ...];
var pop = ['state1 pop', 'state2 pop', ...];
```

Then first of all, `avg` is already wrong. `sum`'s value is running along with the loop turning `avg`'s formula into `sum as of iteration / array length` instead of `sum of all pops / array length`. You should calculate the average beforehand. [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will be your friend.

```
var average = pop.reduce(function(sum, val){return sum + val;}, 0) / pop.length;
```

Now for your filter operation, you can:

1. Zip up both arrays to one array using [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
2. Filter the resulting array with [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
3. Finally, loop through the resulting array using [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Here's sample code:

```js
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska'];
var pop = [4863300, 741894];
var average = pop.reduce(function(sum, val){return sum + val;}) / pop.length;

console.log('Average: ' + average);

states.map(function(state, index) {

  // Convert 2 arrays to an array of objects representing state info
  return { name: state, population: pop[index] };
  
}).filter(function(stateInfo) {
  console.log(stateInfo);

  // Filter each item by returning true on items you want to include
  return stateInfo.population < average;
  
}).forEach(function(stateInfo) {

  // Lastly, loop through your results
  console.log(stateInfo.name + ' has ' + stateInfo.population + ' people');
  
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and suggestions, I didn't really think about my average being incorrect but your suggestions make perfect sense. I've been learning Javascript for about 7 weeks so anything I can learn is really helpful.